# By using replace and regex: I have captured c, but I want to set it at the end of osonant plus “ay” with replace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, regex-group

Here is he link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/pig-latin.

By using replace and regex: I have captured `c`, but I want to set it at the end of `onsonant` plus `ay` using the `replace` function in JavaScript

Here is my code:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {

  let regEx=/([bcd-fgh-klmn-pqrst-vwxyz])/i

  console.log(str.replace(regEx, '$1,'))


}

translatePigLatin("consonant");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Pig Latin is a way of altering English Words. The rules are as
>   follows:
>
> - If a word begins with a consonant, take the first consonant or consonant cluster, move it to the end of the word, and add "ay" to it.
> - If a word begins with a vowel, just add "way" at the end.

A possible solution:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
    if (!/[aeiou]/.test(str)) { // if it does not contain vowels
        return str + "ay";
    } else if (/^[aeiou]/.test(str)) { // if it starts with a vowel
        return str + "way";
    } else { // if it starts with a consonant and has vowels
        let regx = /(.*?)([aeiou])(.*)/i;
        return str.replace(regx, "$2$3$1ay");
    }
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("pig")); // igpay
console.log(translatePigLatin("rythm")); // rythmay
console.log(translatePigLatin("consonant")); // onsonantcay
```

The regular expression `/(.*?)([aeiou])(.*)/i` means:

`(.*?)` match as minimum characters as possible

`([aeiou])` followed by a vowel and

`(.*)` followed by the rest of the string.

By usinig the parenthesis, we are creating backreferences `$1`, `$2`, `$3` that will store each of these values for later use with the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Answer (score 0):

See if that's what you want

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {   
  let regx = /(.*?)([^aeiou])(.*)/i
  console.log(str.replace(regx, '$1$3ay$2'))
} 
  
translatePigLatin("consonant")

// output onsonantayc
```

Your question is a bit vague, if not add more information in the comments

@Edited

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/pig-latin

Comment: I edited my answer, I believe this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  let consonant = /^([^aeiou]+)/i;
  if(!str.match(consonant)) return str.concat("way")
  let sub = str.split(consonant).filter(s => s.length > 0)[0]
  return str.replace(consonant,"").concat(sub).concat("ay")
}
```