# Can I use regex with conditions? How may I do the conditions for words which start in consonants and for words which start in vowels in Javascript

Tags: javascript

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/pig-latin
I want to set the conditions for words which start in vowels and for words which start in consonants:

"- If a word begins with a consonant, take the first consonant or consonant cluster, move it to the end of the word, and add "ay" to it.

- If a word begins with a vowel, just add "way" at the end".

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {

  let regexConsonants=/(.[^aeiou]*)([aeiou]*)(.*)|([aeiou]*)(.[^aeiou]*)(.+)/i

  let replacedConsonantStr=str.replace(regexConsonants, "$2$3$1ay");

  let replacedVowelsStr=str.replace(/(.+)/i,"$1way")
  //console.log(replacedConsonantStr)



for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){

if(str[0]=="a"|str[0]=="e"|str[0]=="i"|str[0]=="o"|str[0]=="u"){
        return replacedConsonantStr;                


   }else{
          return replacedVowelsStr
   }
        console.log(replacedVowelsStr)
}


}

translatePigLatin("algorithm");

//let regex=/(.[^aeiou]*)([aeiou]*)(.*)/i;

 //let replacedStr=str.replace(regex, "$2$3$1ay");
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448161/by-using-replace-and-regex-i-have-captured-c-but-i-want-to-set-it-at-the-end-o/

Comment: Read my answer on that post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61448583/13312580

Answer (score 0):

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {

  let regexConsonants=/(.[^aeiou]*)([aeiou]*)(.*)|([aeiou]*)(.[^aeiou]*)(.+)/i

  let replacedConsonantStr=str.replace(regexConsonants, "$2$3$1ay");

  let replacedVowelsStr=str.replace(/(.+)/i,"$1way")
  //console.log(replacedConsonantStr)





if(str.startsWith('a')|str.startsWith('e')|str.startsWith('i')|str.startsWith('o')|str.startsWith('u')){

             return replacedVowelsStr;
}else{
              return replacedConsonantStr;
}

}

translatePigLatin("algorithm");

//let regex=/(.[^aeiou]*)([aeiou]*)(.*)/i;
```